# Does the random walk theory assume a simple symmetric random walk?

Tags: random-walk, market-efficiency

Does the random walk theory assume a simple symmetric random walk? In other words: does the random walk theory assume that the price rises as often as it falls? I've been looking for an answer for a while but I'm still not sure. Maybe this question is very simple, but I think that it will then be easier for other people to find an answer to this question.

Note: I‘m an undergraduate economics student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random walk theory assumes that stock price can be modeled by:

$$log(S_t)=log(S_{t-1})+\epsilon_t, \epsilon_t~ iid N(0, \sigma^2).$$

In other words, stock price follows a random walk, as described above.

Comment: Okay, if I see that correctly, it should mean that rising and falling prices occur with the same frequency. But if we accept a positive drift, there is a bias towards the positive classes, right?

Comment: Yes, the mean of $\epsilon$ is 0, so equal chances for growth or decline. If you model random walk with drift, i.e., $S_t=\mu+S_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$, then recursively you'll get $S_t=\mu t +S_0+\sum \epsilon_t$. If we assume that $S_0=0$, then expectaion $E(S_t)=\mu t$, which is non-constant and depends on time. If $\mu$ is postitive, then over time mean is increasing, if negative -- then decreasing. So, bias towards negative or positive classes depends on the sign of $\mu$.

Comment: AFAIK, when the term "random walk" is used, they are referrring to log prices following a random walk and no drift ( so symmetric RW )  so the model would be $log(S_t) = log(S_{t-1})  +   \epsilon_t $. In this manner, returns are random with zero mean.

Comment: @markleeds Yes, it is assumed that log prices follow random walk -- edited, thanks. Aside from that, it is common to use random walk with drift. See here, equation 1: https://rodneywhitecenter.wharton.upenn.edu/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/8705.pdf

Comment: @markleeds What do the logarithmized prices mean in this context?

Comment: @Sane How can you explain this positive drift? Many thanks to both of you for your comments.

Comment: @Rainer: Niemann: You just take the log because that implies that $r_t = \epsilon_t$ which means that returns are perfectly random ( normally distributed if we assume that for $\epsilon$ )  with zero mean.  Note that the difference of logs is an approximation to the return for small price changes

Comment: @Sane: Putting the drift in is fine because the random walk  is still symmetric. The only difference one obtains by putting the drift term in is that it implies that, on average, the expected return is  $\mu$ rather than zero. But the rw itself is still perfectly symmetric around $\mu$. ( there's an equal chance for it  to be above or below $\mu$ ).

Comment: @markleeds Does this mean we can determine the constant drift $\mu$ by finding the value where 50% of the relative changes are above and 50% below?

Comment: @markleeds What are common values for a constant drift?

Comment: @Rainer Niemann: The value of $\mu$ would depend on the time frame one is using for the returns. The shorter the time frame, the smaller the value of $\mu$. Your idea for estimating $\mu$ is nice intutively but, if you really believe in the model, then why not just estimate $\mu$ using the standard regression approach. The value of $\mu$ should end up being the same as the average return over the estimation period you because you're estimating an intercept only  regression model.

Comment: Are you sure the random walk theory requires normality? In general, a random walk has nothing to do with normality (even though one is permitted to assume both at once if one wishes to).

Comment: @markleeds: You are right, thanks!

Comment: Hi Richard: the limit of normality ( scaled in the correct way ) is brownian motion so it's probably not a bad idea to assume normality with mean zero for the error term. but you're right that the random walk just requires the martingale relation so as long as the error has term has mean zero, that's probably the only requirement. To be honest, I'm not sure if there's some official definition of the random walk aside from the fact that the log price should be a martingale ( which implies that the expectation of the error should be zero ). thanks for good point.

Comment: @Rainier Niemann: I'm glad if something that I said helped you. good luck.

Comment: @markleeds: Yes, that helped me a lot. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the stockmarket, this is often a first-pass default assumption. Add in a bit of financial spice, however, and you distribute stock returns lognormally (as opposed to normally), then strictly speaking, they cease to be symmetrical. But 99% of people could not tell the difference 99% of the time.

Turning to debt markets, this rapidly falls apart. 99% of the time, the company does not default and I get my coupon. 1% of the time, they do default and I lose 70-75% of my capital. This is clearly not symmetrical. But this can still represent a random walk!

Think of the random walk as a repetitive coin-flipping exercise. At each step, you flip a coin. But the probability of heads does not have to be 50%; and the relative payoff of heads:tails does not have to be 1:-1. Nothing in the maths of random walks requires symmetry.

Except this is often lazily assumed because it makes the entire subject much easier to think about :-)

Comment: Hi @demully, thanks for your answer. Does this mean that there is no such thing as one random walk model in the context of the random walk hypothesis?

Comment: @Demully: Thanks for nice explanation but note that I was talking about equities rather than bonds. Also, you do need symmetry ( well, expectation zero which usually implies symmetry ) in the error term of the random walk because otherwise, the log price will not be a martingale. Basically, you want the expectation of the next log price to be equal to the previous log price ( maybe plus a drift ) so, if the expectation of the error term is not zero, you won't obtain that.